# How to Convert db.runcomand to c#.net MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to convert this command for c# .net?

```
db.logs.aggregate([
   {
 $geoNear: {
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ lng , lat ] },
    distanceField: "dist.distance",
    maxDistance: 5,
    includeLocs: "dist.location",
    num: 1000,
    spherical: true
 },
}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, It's work fine.

```
                    BsonDocument geoPoint = new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {"type","Point"},
                                   {"coordinates",new BsonArray(new Double[]{double.Parse(lon), double.Parse(lat)})}
                                };

                    BsonDocument query = new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$eq", new BsonArray {"City", "Bangkok" }
                                    }
                                };


                    BsonDocument geoNearOptions = new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {"spherical", true},
                                    {"limit", 10000}, //need to test to see what limit is appropriate, should we do a filter first?
                                    {"maxDistance", 400},
                                    {"query",filter},
                                    {"near",geoPoint},
                                    {"distanceField","dist.distance"},
                                    {"includeLocs", "dist.location"},
                                };

                    var stage = new BsonDocumentPipelineStageDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument { { "$geoNear", geoNearOptions } });
                    var colAggregate = collection2.Aggregate().AppendStage(stage).Sort(new BsonDocument { { "_id", 1 } });
```